# intercepting mysql traffic in php

Tags: php, sockets, mysqli

I don't suppose there's a way to, using PHP, intercept what mysql_query sends out and rewrite it before sending it out?

mysqli::__construct has an option parameter $socket.  If streams could be passed for that parameter then you could pass php://memory to it it seems but it doesn't seem to work that way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need that? Isn't there any other way?

Comment: You mention two different API's, one of which is basically deprecated but `mysql_connect` can also take a socket argument. If this is a method of avoiding SQL Injection or something, I'd argue it's a large use of time for a small gain that may be unsuccessful which would be better spent reworking the underlying calls.

Comment: If you need additional functionality to the mysql_query function why don't you wrap it instead of trying to intercept what it does after the fact?

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse, Any attempt to avoid SQL injection after the query is formed will be 100% unsuccessful.  There will be no small gain.  It isn't possible to programmatically determine what is original data and what is original query structure.

Comment: I'm trying to see if it's possible to tunnel mysql connections through phpseclib - a pure PHP SSH implementation.  So mysqli would send the raw data to phpseclib, phpseclib would put it into an SSH packet and send it off and then phpseclib would get the response back and pass the response back to the mysqli functions.

Comment: just in case you missed it, mySQL supports SSL directly. (Sorry if you knew and need the library to do something extra.)

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a proxy server with something like squid that will forward to a database server from the frontend.